# How to put an Enum into a List, using PythonNET and C#.NET?

Tags: c#, python, enums, python.net

I have a NET library I'm using from Python with PythonNET and can't figure out how to put an enum into a List.  It seems Python converts the enum to an integer that won't fit the List datatype.  Here's an example:

```
import clr
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from System import Array, Enum
import MyLibrary

enum = List[MyLibrary.ResultType] #no errors here
enum.Add(MyLibrary.ResultType.PV) 
#TypeError: No method matches given arguments

#and just typing MyLibrary.ResultType.PV I get this result
Out[7]: 0
```

So I tried also creating an array - it will also create an empty one with the enum datatype, but won't allow me to assign a value to it:

```
Array[MyLibrary.ResultType](MyLibrary.ResultType.PV) 
#TypeError: Cannot convert 0 to MyLibrary.ResultType[]
```

Anyone have a solution to this issue?  Appreciate it.

Comment: Please don't add [solved] devices to titles, Matt - we don't use them here. Use the acceptance system instead - thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I had posted on the PythonNET mailing list and wanted the group to see in the email that it was already solved.  Removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my god I can't believe the mistake I made, but here it is.  I wasn't creating the List with an initialization

```
enum = List[MyLibrary.ResultType]() #the missing () was the reason this didn't work!
enum.Add(MyLibrary.ResultType.PV)
```

Now it works just fine.