# Pythonnet: Why are .NET enums type casted to int?

Tags: c#, enums, casting, python.net

Why are .NET enums type casted to int?

E.g.: I want to generate an array of `Objects` where the first element is an `Int32`, the second element is an `Double` and the third element is an enumeration of the type `DateTimeKind`. See the following code:

```
import clr
from System import Array, DateTimeKind, Double, Enum, Int32, Object
a = Array[Object]([None, None, None])
a[0] = Int32(127)
a[1] = Double(12.4)
a[2] = DateTimeKind.Utc
```

But now the third element is of type `int` and not `DateTimeKind`.

I need the array `a` as argument when invoking a method (reflection, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997219/7556646).

I'm as well aware that I can generate a `b = List[DataTimeKind]()` and add elements to that list, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088399/7556646. The list `b` has the right type but when I access an element of the list `b[0]` then it's again an `int`.

So what can I do to cast an `int` to an `enum`?

Comment: From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum). "_An enumeration type (or enum type) is a value type defined by a set of named constants of the underlying integral numeric type. By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type int; _". In C# the real type of a enum can be `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` or `ulong`.

Comment: @DragandDrop: I'm aware of that. But assume I want to call a method `void Test(DateTimeKind arg)` when a second method with the same name exists e.g.: `void Test(double arg)`. I want to call the method with the enum argument. In that case pythonnet says no method match given arguments (int).

Comment: Sorry I'm not from the python world. I took "_Why are .NET enums type casted to int?_" to the C# tag. Given that `DateTimeKind ` is an int [ref](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimekind.cs,f7567dbc80085e11). It looked natural that it was cast to int. I was not teaching nor pendentric, nor trying to answer a domain I have no knowledge about.

Comment: The only info i have is this github issue https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/935, and related issue. I do not have the Py background to try or understand it tho.

Comment: @DragandDrop I saw that github issue as well. But the method I want to call has two arguments of two different types of enums and it exists with the same name and different arguments. So this workaround doesn't help. So I tried to use reflection to call the method. I can choose the right method I want but I've to pass an array of objects where some of the elements need to be of the type enum and not int.

Comment: that related issue as multiple argument in the title https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1099

Comment: So it looks that there is no workaround, `I think we should disable implicit .NET enum <-> Python int conversion in 3.0`.

Comment: Pinging/suscribing/showing interest on the github issue, may help having a path for this. For now there is no pull request solving this. Perhaps you can change the C# signature to accept int and do the converstion on C# side.

Comment: @DragandDrop The C# signature is from an external product and I would like to avoid to write a helper C# assembly.

Comment: Add a C# ddl that consume that part of the external product. It's either that or getting a contributor badge. Btw for that comment chain I think that this question has an answer. and quote the contributor  and related issue. Then we will cleanup  our comment our self. Before the next Thanos snap

Answer (score 1):

This not possible with pythonnet at the moment because pythonnet converts .NET enums to int, see https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1220.

`.NET enums should not be automatically converted to Python int and back`

The only workaround would be to add a C# helper dll and call this helper dll from pythonnet.